# Where I should put images in order to access them from RSForm Pro?

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm trying to change some input element to have a background image. For that I try all this without success:

1) Edit `front.css` at `/components/com_rsform/assets/css` and add this code at the end:

```
.rsform-submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input#continuar {
  background-image: url("../images/boton_continuar.png");
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Of course images exists at `/components/com_rsform/assets/images`

2) Add the code in `Properties > CSS and Javascript` at form in RSForm Pro in administrator side:

```
.rsform-submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input#continuar {
  background-image: url("../images/boton_continuar.png");
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

None of the above works, how I deal with this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where the form is so we can see what the issue is?

Comment: what's happened when you inspect the button with Google chrome? It should give you the full path of the image. If you write your css in your index.php file you can use `background-image: url("<?php echo $this->baseurl;?>/images/boton_continuar.png");`
and upload boton_continuar.png in the folder imlages